# Blue Screen Errors

Tags: windows, bsod, windows-11

Apologies in advance if I didn't post any of this correctly, this is my first time posting here. I have been getting bluescreen errors nonstop. I went to my diagnostic data viewer and noticed there was a hardware error:

Windows

Description
Faulting Application Path: C:\Windows\System32\WerFault.exe
Creation Time: 12/7/2022 5:50:39 PM
Problem: Hardware error
Status: Report queued

Problem signature
Problem Event Name:           LiveKernelEvent
Code:                         124
Parameter 1:                  7
Parameter 2:                  ffffa48628514020
Parameter 3:                  0
Parameter 4:                  0
OS version:                   10_0_22621
Service Pack:                 0_0
Product:                      768_1

Extra information about the problem
Bucket ID: (18446744073709551615)

Files that help describe the problem
WHEA-20221207-1747.dmp
sysdata.xml
WERInternalMetadata.xml
WPR_initiated_DiagTrackMiniLogger_OneTrace_User_Logger_20220920_1_EC_0_inject.etl
WPR_initiated_DiagTrackMiniLogger_OneTrace_User_Logger_20220920_1_EC_0.etl
WPR_initiated_DiagTrackMiniLogger_WPR System Collector_inject.etl
WPR_initiated_DiagTrackMiniLogger_WPR System Collector.etl
memory.csv
sysinfo.txt
WERInternalRequest.xml
WERDataCollectionStatus.txt

I have gotten several bluescreen codes over the past couple of days, but these are the two I had right after the hardware error:

Description
Faulting Application Path:   C:\Windows\System32\WerFault.exe
Creation Time:           12/7/2022 5:50:42 PM
Problem:             Shut down unexpectedly
Status:              Report sent

Problem signature
Problem Event Name:           BlueScreen
Code:                         be
Parameter 1:                  fffff80576bc1500
Parameter 2:                  9000008857e6121
Parameter 3:                  ffffc9829ea0e970
Parameter 4:                  b
OS version:                   10_0_22621
Service Pack:                 0_0
Product:                      768_1

Extra information about the problem
Bucket ID:           AV_volmgr!VmDeviceControl (18446744073709551615)

Then this one:

Description
Faulting Application Path:   C:\Windows\System32\WerFault.exe
Creation Time:           12/7/2022 5:50:42 PM
Problem:             Shut down unexpectedly
Status:              Report sent

Problem signature
Problem Event Name:           BlueScreen
Code:                         1a
Parameter 1:                  41792
Parameter 2:                  ffffbc80cd40da28
Parameter 3:                  4000
Parameter 4:                  0
OS version:                   10_0_22621
Service Pack:                 0_0
Product:                      768_1

Extra information about the problem
Bucket ID:           MEMORY_CORRUPTION_ONE_BIT (18446744073709551615)

Answer (score 0):

> Description Faulting Application Path:
> C:\Windows\System32\WerFault.exe

This is a driver error.

Update all the drivers in your computer. Best way is to get the Computer Manufacturer's Driver Update App and use that.

Update BIOS (UEFI) as part of your driver updates

When this has been completed, use the Manufacturer's Hardware Diagnostic App and test all hardware.   Look for memory errors.